# Scraping table data after applying filter

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from this website: http://nepalstock.com/indices . I am not being able to scrape table data after changing value of '**Select Indices or Sub Indices**'
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0WMn.png

Since the url does not change, I do not know how to proceed on this.

So far, this is my code:

```
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=requests.get("http://nepalstock.com/indices")
soup=BeautifulSoup(html.content,"html.parser")
lst=[]
for row in soup.find_all("tr"):
    l=[]
    for td in row.find_all("td"):
        l.append(td.get_text())
    lst.append(l)
df=pandas.DataFrame(lst[1:])
df.head()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892543/scraping-a-response-from-a-selected-option-in-dropdown-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scraping a response from a selected option in dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892543/scraping-a-response-from-a-selected-option-in-dropdown-list)