# python - scraping tables by navigating different options in drop down list

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from this site: https://www.koreabaseball.com/Record/Team/Hitter/Basic1.aspx

The default year has been set as 2018 (the most recent year) by the website and I want to scrape all available years.

A very similar question has been asked 4 years ago but it doesn't seem to work.

[scraping a response from a selected option in dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892543/scraping-a-response-from-a-selected-option-in-dropdown-list)

All it does for me when I run it is print out the table from the default year regardless of parameter I assign.

I can't access different years via url since url doesn't change when I select options in the drop down box. So I tried using webdriver and xpath.

Here is my code that I attempted:

```
url = "https://www.koreabaseball.com/Record/Team/Hitter/Basic1.aspx"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Applications/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)

year = 2017
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$cphContents$cphContents$cphContents$ddlSeason$ddlSeason']/option[@value='"+str(year)+"']").click()
page = driver.page_source
bs_obj = BSoup(page, 'html.parser')

header_row = bs_obj.find_all('table')[0].find('thead').find('tr').find_all('th')
body_rows = bs_obj.find_all('table')[0].find('tbody').find_all('tr')
footer_row = bs_obj.find_all('table')[0].find('tfoot').find('tr').find_all('td')

headings = []
footings = []

for heading in header_row:
    headings.append(heading.get_text())

for footing in footer_row:
    footings.append(footing.get_text())

body = []

for row in body_rows:
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    row_temp = []
    for i in range(len(cells)):
        row_temp.append(cells[i].get_text())
    body.append(row_temp)

driver.quit()
print(headings)
print(body)
print(footings)
```

I expected the output to print out the table from the year 2017 as I specified but the actual output prints out the table from the year 2018 (the default year). Can anyone give me ideas to solve this problem?

Edit: I just found out that what I see by doing "Inspect" is different from what I get from "Page Source". Specifically, page source still has "2018" as the Select option (which is not what I want), whereas Inspect shows me "2017" is selected. But still stuck on how to use "Inspect" rather than page source.

Comment: your page is still for 2018 ,when you find 2017 click it so that the table changes to 2017 records

Comment: i do click it on the 6th line of the code (not counting blank lines). scroll the code to the right and you'll see the rest of the code on that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup
url = "https://www.koreabaseball.com/Record/Team/Hitter/Basic1.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Applications/chromedriver")
year = 2017
driver.get(url)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$cphContents$cphContents$cphContents$ddlSeason$ddlSeason']/option[@value='"+str(year)+"']"))
)
element.click()
#its better to wait till some text has changed
#but this will do for now


WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(
        (By.XPATH, "//select[@name='ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$cphContents$cphContents$cphContents$ddlSeason$ddlSeason']/option[@selected='selected']"),
        str(year)
    )
)
#sleep for some time to complete ajax load of the table
#sleep(10)
page = driver.page_source
bs_obj = BSoup(page, 'html.parser')

header_row = bs_obj.find_all('table')[0].find('thead').find('tr').find_all('th')
body_rows = bs_obj.find_all('table')[0].find('tbody').find_all('tr')
footer_row = bs_obj.find_all('table')[0].find('tfoot').find('tr').find_all('td')

headings = []
footings = []

for heading in header_row:
    headings.append(heading.get_text())

for footing in footer_row:
    footings.append(footing.get_text())

body = []

for row in body_rows:
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    row_temp = []
    for i in range(len(cells)):
        row_temp.append(cells[i].get_text())
    body.append(row_temp)

driver.quit()
print(headings)
print(body)
```

Output

```
['순위', '팀명', 'AVG', 'G', 'PA', 'AB', 'R', 'H', '2B', '3B', 'HR', 'TB', 'RBI', 'SAC', 'SF']
[['1', 'KIA', '0.302', '144', '5841', '5142', '906', '1554', '292', '29', '170', '2414', '868', '55', '56'], ['2', '두산', '0.294', '144', '5833', '5102', '849', '1499', '270', '20', '178', '2343', '812', '48', '47'], ['3', 'NC', '0.293', '144', '5790', '5079', '786', '1489', '277', '19', '149', '2251', '739', '62', '48'], ['4', '넥센', '0.290', '144', '5712', '5098', '789', '1479', '267', '30', '141', '2229', '748', '21', '42'], ['5', '한화', '0.287', '144', '5665', '5030', '737', '1445', '261', '16', '150', '2188', '684', '85', '38'], ['6', '롯데', '0.285', '144', '5671', '4994', '743', '1425', '250', '17', '151', '2162', '697', '76', '32'], ['7', 'LG', '0.281', '144', '5614', '4944', '699', '1390', '216', '20', '110', '1976', '663', '76', '55'], ['8', '삼성', '0.279', '144', '5707', '5095', '757', '1419', '255', '36', '145', '2181', '703', '58', '55'], ['9', 'KT', '0.275', '144', '5485', '4937', '655', '1360', '274', '17', '119', '2025', '625', '62', '45'], ['10', 'SK', '0.271', '144', '5564', '4925', '761', '1337', '222', '15', '234', '2291', '733', '57', '41']]
```

You have to wait for some time  for the table to refresh after you click. Also read my comments. Sleep is not the best option.

**Edit:**

I have edited the code to wait till the selected text is the year. The code no longer uses sleep.

Comment: thank you so much! I was stuck on this for a few days and it finally works!!! btw how would you know when text has changed? is there a certain library I can use?

Comment: @JoshuaKim Read this http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html

Comment: appreciate a lot for the reply