# Scraping a table based on the option value from a drop down

Tags: pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape values from a table after changing the option value from the dropdown. I found this stack overflow post [scraping a response from a selected option in dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892543/scraping-a-response-from-a-selected-option-in-dropdown-list), but I still haven't managed to get it working.

The site I'm trying to scrape is:
https://www.myfxbook.com/forex-market/correlation

I'm trying to get the "5-minutes" chart but it still returns the default table of "1 day".

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.myfxbook.com/forex-market/correlation"
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    data ={"timeScales": "5"}
    response = session.post(url, data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

pd.read_html(str(soup))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape the Table, you can send a `POST` request to [here](http://%22https://www.myfxbook.com/updateCorrelationSymbolMenu.json%22) by adding the **correct `headers` and `data`**

To select a different "Timeframe" from the dropdown, modify the value of `timeScale` (below) in the `data` dictionary. It seems that the values should be based on minutes, for example, to select the "5 minutes" table, use `"timeScale": "5"`, or to select the "1 week" table, use `timeScale: 10080`.

In your example, to select the "5 day" table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36",
    "referer": "https://www.myfxbook.com/",
}

data = {
    "colSymbols": "8,9,10,6,7,1,4,2,5,3",
    "rowSymbols": "8,47,9,10,1234,11,103,12,46,1245,6,13,14,15,17,18,7,2114,19,20,21,22,1246,23,1,1233,107,24,25,4,2872,137,48,1236,1247,2012,2,1863,3240,26,49,27,28,2090,131,5,29,5779,31,34,3,36,37,38,2076,40,41,42,43,45,3005,3473,50,2115,2603,2119,1815,2521,51,12755,5435,5079,10064,1893",
    # Change the value of `timeScale` to get the different Timeframe, the value should be by minutes, for example to get 1 week, use `10080`
    "timeScale": "5",
    "z": "0.6367404250506281",
}

response = requests.post(
    "https://www.myfxbook.com/updateCorrelationSymbolMenu.json",
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
).json()

table_html = response["content"]["marketCorrelationTable"]
soup = BeautifulSoup(table_html, "html.parser")
```